# Does additional variable declaration consume more memory?

Tags: c#, .net, memory

Consider this example:

```
public const string SelectQueryFormat = "SELECT {0} FROM {1}";

public string BuildSelectQuery_1(string tableName, string columnName)
{
    return string.Format(SelectQueryFormat, columnName, tableName);
}

public string BuildSelectQuery_2(string tableName, string columnName)
{
    string rtn = string.Format(SelectQueryFormat, columnName, tableName);
    return rtn;
}
```

Both `BuildSelectQuery_1` and `BuildSelectQuery_2` are equivalent and return the same result. However, it is easier to debug with `BuildSelectQuery_2` because you can see (and even change) the processed result in the `rtn` variable before returning.

The question now is, does `BuildSelectQuery_2` consume more memory because of the allocation of the additional `rtn` variable? Is it better to use `BuildSelectQuery_1` or `BuildSelectQuery_2`?

Comment: In short: It doesn't. Both functions compile to the same IL code. When in doubt, see what instructions your function compiled into. But overall, you shouldn't be looking to make optimizations on this level anyway - choose whatever's more readable.

Comment: Agreed. Every developer, at some point in there life, comes to the conclusion that if they can just learn the right "rules" then they'll always write the most efficient code possible. It doesn't work that way. There'd by billions of rules and most of them would have so many variations and caveats that they barely function as rules. Write *clear*, understandable code, and (in parallel) set performance *goals*. Then **measure** your code and identify the *actual* areas where performance isn't adequate and focus your attention on the *specifics* of the hotspots you have.